# Multitable Join Taking Too Long

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having an issue with this query.  It's taking entirely too long.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.contactid ) AS tot
FROM todo_contacts a
    LEFT JOIN contactlists b ON a.calllistid = b.listid
    LEFT JOIN contact_list_relationship c ON c.listid = b.listid
    INNER JOIN contacts d ON ( d.contactid = c.contactid OR a.contactid = d.contactid ) AND d.customerid =  '100'
WHERE a.customerid =  '100'
```

todo_contacts can contact a contactid directly relating to the contacts table, or a contactlistid relating to the contactlists table.

The problem really seems to be this.  If I insert 1 row into todo_contacts with a contactlistid in which the contact list has 50,000 relations in contact_list_relationship (which stores the relationship between contactlists & contacts) the query is VERY (taking minutes) slow.  If I remove the bit of the query `OR a.contactid = d.contactid` the query takes less than a second.

I really need the query to return a total contactid's if they are in both a contactlist, or added directly.

Anyone know why that OR part of the query is adding so much additional processing time considering there is only 1 row in a and the contactid is null.

Here's a explain on the query:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a   ref customerid,contactid    customerid  4   const   1    
1   SIMPLE  b   eq_ref  PRIMARY,listID  PRIMARY 8   a.calllistid    1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  c   ref listID  listID  4   b.listID    156  
1   SIMPLE  d   ref PRIMARY,customerid  customerid  5   const   57409   Using where
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a union all instead of the OR.

it's messy and you will have to almost duplicate the query but will probably run faster. try something like this:

select sum(q.tot)
from (
SELECT COUNT( d.contactid ) AS tot
FROM todo_contacts a
    LEFT JOIN contactlists b ON a.calllistid = b.listid
    LEFT JOIN contact_list_relationship c ON c.listid = b.listid
    INNER JOIN contacts d ON ( d.contactid = c.contactid) AND d.customerid =  '100'

union all

SELECT COUNT( d.contactid ) AS tot
FROM todo_contacts a
    INNER JOIN contacts d ON (a.contactid = d.contactid ) AND d.customerid =  '100'

WHERE a.customerid =  '100') q

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I forgot to put the DISTINCT in the initial question, that's needed.  I wouldn't be able to add the 2 queries together because of the duplicates.

Comment: I ended up splitting it up and used a `COUNT` with a `DISTINCT` after the union.  Thanks!